# How can I stop the native clock app's countdown-timer from throwing one notification per minute?

Tags: notifications, settings, clock

I have Android 8.1.0 installed, and when using the countdown of the native clock app, it throws one notification per minute. I would just like to turn that off.

In the Settings under:

- Apps & notifications

  - Clock

    - App notifications

      - ALARM_NOTIFICATION_LOW_CHANNEL

        - Importance

I picked "Low - No sound or visual interruption".

When I listen to audio from another app, the timer doesn't make a noise, but it pauses the audio I am listening to and shows a notification dropdown. This dropdown is also annoying while using a browser, because it overlaps the URL bar and the top part of a site...

Unfortunately, googling made me no wiser. Thanks for any tips on how to turn that off.

Comment: Which Android device are you using?

Comment: Archos Access 50s 4G

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changed the settings in ALARM_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL, instead of ALARM_NOTIFICATION_LOW_CHANNEL and that fixed it.

Comment: Would like to accept this answer, since the issue is solved, but the interface says I need to wait two days ...